# prove that the ideal $I=(x,xyx,\dotsc,xy^nx,\dotsc)$ cannot be generated by a finite number of polynimials.

Tags: ring-theory

The ring is $K\langle x,y \rangle$

So we have to assume that exist a finite number.

Let $f_1,\dotsc,f_m$ a finite number of polynomials.

How we can arrive at a contradiction?

Comment: I = { g1x+g2xyx +....gnxy^nx| g1....gn from K}

Comment: these are polinomials without rest . f1....fm contains a finite number of variables xi, i<n0

Comment: This looks like a job for induction.  Base case:  Does $(x) \supseteq (x,xyx)$?

Comment: no . (x,xyx) ⊇ (x)

Comment: is $xy^2x \in (x, xyx)$?

Comment: no  because we can't obtain it from (x,xyx)

Comment: and we can continue with xy^3x ...and so on ?

Comment: an we have that xy^nx not include in (x,xyx) ?

Comment: As I say, this is a job for induction.  This means you have to explain *why* you can't have the various $xy^nx$ in the smaller ideals.

Comment: I suppose the polynomials are noncommutative ? Otherwise you would have written $x^2y,x^2y^2$ etc.

Comment: Yes, i know that

Comment: So i have to prove by induction that xy^nx is not include in ( x , xyx)?

Comment: Am  i right? Because i don't know how to start